# How to do a sorted distinct query for a specific set of records on Mongo?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

From a moderate sized collection (~1m rows) containing stock information, I want to query for a specific company/stock, and then for that company, return the highest return distinct by the date.

Here is a representation of the data (fields omitted for brevity:

```
{ 
    "Symbol" : "AAPL", 
    "Expiration" : "2019-10-18T04:00:00.000+0000", 
    "flatreturn" : 0.82, 

}
{ 
    "Symbol" : "AAPL", 
    "Expiration" : "2019-10-18T04:00:00.000+0000", 
    "flatreturn" : 0.92, 

}
{ 
    "Symbol" : "AAPL", 
    "Expiration" : "2019-10-18T04:00:00.000+0000", 
    "flatreturn" : 0.52, 

}
{ 
    "Symbol" : "AAPL", 
    "Expiration" : "2019-10-18T04:00:00.000+0000", 
    "flatreturn" : 1.82, 

}
{ 
    "Symbol" : "AAPL", 
    "Expiration" : "2019-10-22T04:00:00.000+0000", 
    "flatreturn" : 0.43, 

}
{ 
    "Symbol" : "AAPL", 
    "Expiration" : "2019-10-22T04:00:00.000+0000", 
    "flatreturn" : 6.92, 

}
{ 
    "Symbol" : "AAPL", 
    "Expiration" : "2019-10-22T04:00:00.000+0000", 
    "flatreturn" : 0.12, 

}
{ 
    "Symbol" : "AAPL", 
    "Expiration" : "2019-10-22T04:00:00.000+0000", 
    "flatreturn" : 0.01, 

}
```

Obviously the data set is larger with more than just AAPL but for illustrative purposes, just showing a subset of data.

I am able to find a specific stock, ordered by expiration and flat return. However, that obviously doesn't give me distinct values as I just want a single record for each expiration group.

```
db.getCollection("stocks").find(
    { 
        "Symbol" : "AAPL"
    }
).sort(
    { 
        "Expiration" : 1.0, 
        "flatreturn" : -1.0
    }
);
```

The output I'm desiring is for a specific stock, find the highest return within each group of dates. So for the above dataset, the desired return data would be:

```
{ 
    "Symbol" : "AAPL", 
    "Expiration" : "2019-10-18T04:00:00.000+0000", 
    "flatreturn" : 1.82, 

}

{ 
    "Symbol" : "AAPL", 
    "Expiration" : "2019-10-22T04:00:00.000+0000", 
    "flatreturn" : 6.92, 

}
```

In that desired return dataset, I get the highest return in the 2019-10-18 group and similarly for the 2019-10-22 group.

Appreciate any guidance on structuring a query. By way of more information, if this isn't possible in Mongo, I guess the argument can be made to do it in JS (Node) but given my dataset for a particular stock will return about 1000 records, I wasn't sure about the efficiency of doing the distinct query in JS (or, indeed, how to do that in JS).

Comment: You have to use $aggregation and group by expiration, then get max of flatReturn.

Comment: @Lucia That's great...thanks for the info. That was the guidance I needed to make headway and get the queried constructed.